# Permutations of elements of a list in Python

Tags: python, list, python-itertools

I have a list `A`. I want specific permutations such that no location is occupied by the same element more than once in a list. I present the current and expected outputs. I also want the code to work for any length of `A`.

```
from itertools import permutations

A = [1, 2, 3]

# Generate all possible permutations and convert tuples to lists
all_permutations = [list(perm) for perm in permutations(A)]

# Print the permutations
for perm in all_permutations:
    print(perm)
```

The current output is

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 3, 2]
[2, 1, 3]
[2, 3, 1]
[3, 1, 2]
[3, 2, 1]
```

The expected output is

```
[1,2,3]
[3,1,2]
[2,3,1]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you want to rotate a list by `i` elements for all possible values of `i`.
Try something like this:

```
A = [1, 2, 3]

def rotate(a, i):
    return a[i:] + a[:i]

all_rotations = [rotate(A, i) for i in range(len(A))]

# Print the permutations
for r in all_rotations:
    print(r)
```

Output is

```
[1, 2, 3]
[2, 3, 1]
[3, 1, 2]
```

If you want the exact output in your question (`[1,2,3], [3,1,2], [2,3,1]`) just rotate by `-i` instead of `i`.

Comment: It works! Is there another way that every time I get different lists but again abiding by the condition that no location is occupied by the same element more than once?

Comment: Take a copy of your list, `random.shuffle` it, then use it as `A` in the code above. You could also look at various approaches to the "Latin Square" problem, which is what you have here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25984746/creating-a-latin-square-program-in-python

Answer (score 1):

a different approach, just following same solution as of @carsten

```
>>> A = [1, 2, 3]
>>> new_A = A + A
>>> new_A
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
>>> for i in range(len(A)):
...     sol = new_A[i:i+len(A)]
...     print(sol)
...
[1, 2, 3]
[2, 3, 1]
[3, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will work :

```
def my_fun(l,r):
    for i in range(len(l)):
        r.append(l.copy())
        l.insert(0,l.pop())
    return r

result = []
out = my_fun([1,2,3,4],result)
for o in out:
    print(o)
```

Comment: This prints the permutations but doesn't retain them. In OP's code, the permutations are all retained in `all_permutations`, ready for later use.

Comment: @slothrop, We can add an empty list in the loop and append the generated lists in the list, like this we can retain all the generated list.

Comment: The ouput now is `[[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]`

Comment: @slothrop, yes, now anyone can iterate this list and make a print, I have just written it as if the elements can be retained. Anyway, I have corrected it now. Thanks

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it mutates the **same** list. It doesn't produce each permutation as a separate object.

Comment: @slothrop, not sure if the author has concern about the separate object otherwise it would be mentioned in the question.

Comment: I can't believe OP would be happy for the `all_permutations` list to contain multiple references to the same list object. In any case, look at the output. The program just prints `[1, 2, 3, 4]` 4 times.

Comment: @slothrop, my bad I need to do a shallow copy of the lists, thanks for the correction. I have updated the code.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**